# What is the sufficient condition for optimality of minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, karush-kuhn-tucker

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Sufficient_conditions), "the necessary conditions are sufficient for optimality if the objective function of a maximization problem is a concave function, the inequality constraints are continuously differentiable convex functions and the equality constraints are affine functions".  What about the case for minimization problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same, except for changing the conditions to "objective function of a minimization problem is a convex function"

Indeed, this is equivalent because the optimal argument values for minimizing a function are the same as those for maximizing the negative of the function; and the negative of a concave function is a convex function.

Comment: Do you mean "objective function of a **minimization** problem is a convex function"?

Comment: Yes. My answer originally had a typo.